# How can I convert an array of URLs to HTML links?

Tags: javascript

I have NextJS app with an array of URLs that I want to convert to HTML links.

First, I tried the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57981196/creating-a-list-of-links-from-an-array) using the following code:

```js
    var list = document.createElement('ul'); // Create the list element
    $("body").append(list)
    $('ul').attr("id", "ticketList");
    $.each(yvars, function(i, yvars) {
        $("#ticketList").append("<li><a href='https://jeng.internal.com/browse/"+arr+"'  id="+arr+"_link>"+arr+"</a></li>");
    })
    return (
        <>
            <h1>{yname}</h1>
            <h2>{ydesc}</h2>
            <div>{list}</div>
        </>
    )
```

...and got this error:

[image]

Then I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22928521/514708):

```js
    for (let i = 0; i < yvars.length; i++) {
        result = result + " <a href='" + yvars[i] + "'>" + "Technique " + alf[i] + "</a><br>";
    }
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = result

    return (
        <>
            <h1>{yname}</h1>
            <h2>{ydesc}</h2>
            <div id='results'></div>
        </>
    )
```

...and got this error:
[image]

What is the preferred way of doing this?

Update:
One approach that is *close* to a solution is this construct:

```js
    for (let i = 0; i < yvars.length; i++) {
        result = result + " <a href='" + yvars[i] + "'>" + "Technique " + alf[i] + "</a><br>";
    }

    return (
        <>
            <h1>{yname}</h1>
            <h2>{ydesc}</h2>
            {result}
        </>
    )
```

It causes the web page to look like this (I've redacted the URLs):
[image]

Comment: your first error is in regards to jQuery. just need to define $. and second error is due to there being no id in the html for 'results'. check your html

Comment: 2nd error is that html needs to be ```div id="results"``` and not in curly braces.

Comment: Thanks, @Rick.  How do you define $.?  That isn't in the original post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57981666/514708 (or at least it isn't obvious to me).

Comment: I think you are returning after the ```document.getElementbyId``` which is why it cannot get ```results```. Somehow do one thing that make the html first and then do ```document.getElementbyId```. Because html is not made when you do ```document.getElementbyId```.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JQuery - $ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using map method and put all elements inside a link html tag

```
const linkElements = yvars.map((url) => {
  return (
    <li>
      <a href={`https://jeng.internal.com/browse/${url}`} id={`${url}_link`}>
        {url}
      </a>
    </li>
  );
});

return (
  <>
    <h1>{yname}</h1>
    <h2>{ydesc}</h2>
    <ul>{linkElements}</ul>
  </>
);
```